# Question for product and inverse in group theory I think

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I have a question which I assume is under Group or set theory. I have attempted to answer it but I have now a colleague is saying I am wrong. Need your wisdom on it please.

Question: Consider the element $\alpha = (125)(476)$ and $\beta = (142)(3567)$ of $S_7$. Find $\alpha\beta$, $\beta\alpha$, $\alpha^2$ and $\alpha^{-1}$ (where for x  $\in$ {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, $(\alpha\beta) (x)$ is defined to be $\alpha(\beta(x)))$.

My Answer:

$\alpha\beta$ = {(125,142),(125,3567),(476,142),(476,3567)}

$\beta\alpha$ = {(142,125),(142,476),(3567,125),(3567,476)}

$\alpha^2$ = {(125,125),(125,476),(476,125),(476,476)}

$\alpha^{-1}$ = (476)(125)

I thank you very much for your time and greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Looks like notation problems.  Product of two elements of $S_7$ should be in $S_7$.  $\alpha$ maps for example $1$ to $2$ so $\alpha^{-1}$ should map $2$ to $1$.  What you wrote for $\alpha^{-1}$ is the same element as $\alpha$

Comment: Greetings are discouraged, thus I removed it. [I agree that the specific greeting used raises additional issues, but greetings should be removed regardless.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha = (125)(476)$, then $\alpha$ maps $1\mapsto2$, $2\mapsto5$, $5\mapsto1, 4\mapsto7, 7\mapsto6, 6\mapsto4$, and $3\mapsto3.$

Therefore $\alpha^{-1}$ is given by $(152)(467)$.

$\alpha\beta=(125)(476)(142)(3567)$ maps $1\mapsto4\mapsto7, 2\mapsto1\mapsto2, 3\mapsto5\mapsto1, 4\mapsto2\mapsto5$, $5\mapsto6\mapsto4$,

$6\mapsto7\mapsto6,$ and $7\mapsto3\mapsto3$.  Therefore. $\alpha\beta$ is given by $(173)(45)$.

I hope that with this knowledge you can now compute $\beta\alpha$ and $\alpha^2$.

You could also note that $\alpha^3$ is the identity so $\alpha^2=\alpha^{-1}$.

Comment: May I please be a haflwit and say I cannot understand the mapping logic. Could you suggest a reading that could make me understand how you are making this mapping please?

Comment: There’s a good section in Artin’s *Algebra* if I remember correctly.  Also see [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)

Comment: In cycle notation, $(125)$ means $1\mapsto2, 2\mapsto5,$ and $5\mapsto1$

Comment: It’s worth noting that you are composing the permutations right-to-left; i.e., as functions: $\alpha\beta$ means “do $\beta$ first, then to $\alpha$, to $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin:  yes, I was following what OP wrote in that regard